# How to prevent 403 errors in HTTP requests sent by PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl, fopen

I am using the following script to post data to an external site.  In the example below, $method, $url, and $postdata have already been gathered by the user.

```
foreach($postdata as $key => $value) 
{ 
    $data .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}

if ($method == 'POST') {

    // Set headers
    $headers = array('http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "accept-language: en\r\n" . 
            "Host: $host\r\n" .
            "Referer: $url\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => $data));

    // Send request and retreive response
    $context = stream_context_create($headers);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);

} else if ($method == 'GET') {

    // Set headers
    $headers = array('http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "accept-language: en\r\n" . 
            "Host: $host\r\n" .
            "Referer: $url\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"));

    // Append url
    $url .= '?' . $data;

    // Send request and retreive response
    $context = stream_context_create($headers);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);

} else {
    echo 'Invalid method.';
}
```

It works fine in most cases, however some sites will send back a 403 Forbidden, ostensibly because they don't like fopen() requests.  Is there a way around this?  If I use cURL instead will it prevent the 403?  And, if so, what would be the cURL way of doing the above?  Thanks.

Comment: 403 has little to do with fopen vs cURL, but rather the fact that it doesn't like your call in general. This could be due to a lack of referer (or a referer that it doesn't like, invoking hotlink protection). It could also mean the URL you're trying to access is password protected, simply forbidden, or requires a specific session cookie. This really varies from site to site so there isn't a blanket answer. Having said that, I would definitely suggest using cuRL in general (and not scraping sites that don't wish to be).

Comment: I don't think its the referer because I'm setting that to the requested url.  And it's none of those other things.  I'll look into a cURL solution though.  And I'm not scraping sites :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to ensure you pass a USER-AGENT along with your headers. I've worked on projects which required us to log into remote systems so we could pull data, but on some of these systems, if we didn't pass a valid user-agent we would not gain access, even though the login credentials were set correctly.